# Calculate probabilities with confidence intervals of integers exceeding certain values from a negative binomial regression model

Tags: regression, probability, confidence-interval, data-visualization, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm fairly new to negative binomial regression models, so I hope my question makes sense. So far, I already found this answer to this old question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213315/how-to-calculate-the-predicted-probability-of-negative-binomial-regression-model) in which the person answering showed how upon having fitted a negative binomial model to find the probability of a particular integer value given x.

Say we have the following data

```
set.seed(1)
x = seq(-2, 6, .1)
y = rnbinom(length(x), mu = exp(x), size = .5)
```

we fit a negative binomial model

```
require(MASS)
fit = glm.nb(y ~ x)
```

and find the probability for, say, `y=10` given `x=2` using `theta` from `fit`

```
pred.y <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = 2), type = "response")
dnbinom(10, mu = pred.y, size = fit$theta)
```

`0.02562813`

Regarding my question, I would like to visualize the results of my negative binomial model as probabilities of certain integer values of interest. Ideally, I'd like to plot the probability of y exceeding a certain integer value of interest over all x for which I'd also want to provide confidence interval bands. Based upon the answer mentioned above, I tried the following:

get predicted values with standard errors over all observed x

```
pred.y <- predict(fit, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
```

use `1 - pnbinom(3, mu = exp(pred.y$fit), size = fit$theta)` to, in this case, calculate the probability that y exceeds 3. (and with dnbinom as shown in the answer above I figure I'd get the probability that y = 3)

To calculate confidence intervals I do the same but add/substract 1.96 * `pred.y$se.fit` to `pred.y$fit` resulting in the following plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 1 - pnbinom(3, size = fit$theta, mu = exp(pred.y$fit - qnorm(.975) * pred.y$se.fit)),
                  ymax = 1 - pnbinom(3, size = fit$theta, mu = exp(pred.y$fit + qnorm(.975) * pred.y$se.fit))),
              alpha = .25) +
  geom_path(aes(y = 1 - pnbinom(3, size = fit$theta, mu = exp(pred.y$fit)))) +
  labs(y = "Probability y > 3") +
  theme_bw(12)
```

[image: Probability of y exceeding 3 over all observed x]

**My question now is, if that is a valid way to calculate confidence bands and visualize results from a negative binomial model and if not, where I made an error in my thinking? How can I get confidence intervals for probabilities of y exceeding certain integer values from a negative binomial model?**